# Error when connecting on Soap Service via Android

Tags: android, soap

What i want to try (and nearly flipping out) is to connect to a soap service via android. Here is my code:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addPropterty("###", "###");
request.addProperty("user", "####");
request.addProperty("pwd", "####");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

String resultData = response.getProperty("ort").toString();
```

My privates are:

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/Finder/Finder/###";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/Finder/Finder/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "get##XY";
private static String URL = "http://###.at/###/Finder/Finder.asmx";
```

In the  line where i want to get the Response, i get the following error:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Value cannot be null.
```

I nearly tried everything and read a lot in forums and so on but wasn´t able to find anything that helped me. I tried to set the dotNet variable to true/false, androidHttpTransport.debug true/false, setXmlVersionTag yes/no...

Can ANYBODY help me please?

Comment: how do you mean that? can you give me an example? thx

Comment: Wree you able to figure it out